# For each in list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider I have a tuple in Python

```
numbers = (('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3), ('Four', 4))
```

I want to create a `numbers_dict` in dictionary

```
numbers_dict = {}
for number in numbers:
    numbers_dict[number[0]] = number[1]
```

and so I get

```
numbers_dict = {
  'One': 1,
  'Two': 2,
  'Three': 3,
  'Four': 4,
}
```

Can I do something simpler using the syntax

```
numbers_dict = [n[0] : n[1] for n in numbers]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `numbers` *directly* to the [`dict()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
numbers_dict = dict(numbers)
```

From the documentation:

> If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object. Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

Your `numbers` tuple is such an iterable, and each element in it is a `(key, value)` pair.

Demo:

```
>>> numbers = (('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3), ('Four', 4))
>>> dict(numbers)
{'One': 1, 'Four': 4, 'Three': 3, 'Two': 2}
```

You could use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) too, but that's really overkill here; only use that when you do something more meaningful for each key or value. But for completeness sake, that'd look like this:

```
numbers_dict = {k: v for k, v in numbers}
```